# React PDF: Annotations for a rotated PDF document do not align

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

When I use [react-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf) to render a [rotated pdf document](https://neon-bombolone-4a0569.netlify.app/sample-rotated.pdf) containing links, the annotation layer renders with a rotation different from the document. Therefore, the links do not align.

I have deployed an example showing that the highlighted links do not align with the pdf's links.

- **[Deployed example](https://neon-bombolone-4a0569.netlify.app/)**
- [Github Repo for the example](https://github.com/Auroratide/react-pdf-annotation-rotation)

Here's an image of what I see:

[image: Annotated links, highlighted red, do not match with the blue links in the pdf]

And here's the code I am using to render the PDF:

```
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf/dist/esm/entry.parcel2'
import 'react-pdf/dist/esm/Page/AnnotationLayer.css'

export const Root = () => {
    return (
        <Document file="sample-rotated.pdf">
            <Page pageNumber={1} renderTextLayer={false} renderAnnotationLayer={true} />
            <Page pageNumber={2} renderTextLayer={false} renderAnnotationLayer={true} />
        </Document>
    )
}
```

Is this a bug or is there something I'm missing with regard to how I ought to be rendering rotated PDFs? If it's a bug, I'll happily make an issue for it.

As a workaround, I'm able to manually rotate the annotation layer itself so everything matches up, but I can't help but feel I'm missing something here.

Comment: Any solution to this? I use pdf.js library only and with newest version i face the same issue.